# How to automate custom sequential numbering in Excel

Tags: excel, numbers, sequence

I am using excel to number fields. Each field has various numbers of subcomponents to each. I need them to be numbered in the format of #.#.# (i.e. 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 1.3.1, etc). Is there a function, VBA, or macro that will allow me to do this automatically?

My issue is that when I need to add or remove any rows, I manually have to renumber all fields to maintain sequence.

Comment: What seems to be the biggest challenge is what comes next - For example, how would Excel know that after 1.1.2 you're meant to go to 1.2.1 and not 1.1.3?? Can you explain your question / logic a bit more??

Comment: Have you try always do renumbering from the top to the bottom cell in every row deletion and row insertion